# Will the garbage collector free variables in alternative expressions of a tryCatch statement?

Tags: r, memory-management, error-handling, garbage-collection, try-catch

I'm trying to lean how to use tryCatch() in R. I came across [this tutorial](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) that presented a minimal example of tryCatch() syntax:

[image]

The red arrow points to where my concern lies: To prevent memory leaks do we have to explicitly delete variables that were assigned in alternatively evaluated expressions in a tryCatch() function? Or call the garbage collector, gc()? Or will it somehow be done automatically? (if so, then what is the point of `finally = { }`"?)

For example, what would I have to type in place of the `# clean-up code??` line?

```
result <- tryCatch({

  a <- "Try this" # expression to try

}, warning=function(war){ 

  b <- "Warning"  # expression to deal with warning 

}, error=function(err){

  c <- "Error"    # expression to deal with error 

}, finally={

  # cleanup code ??

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has a garbage collector so generally there is no need to worry about preventing memory leaks or explicitly running the garbage collector -- this is done for you. The garbage collector reclaims memory when no symbols reference it. Because the symbols in the body of the `tryCatch()` are still in scope, they are not eligible for collection in the `finally` clause. On the other hand, symbols referenced in the error handler are no longer in scope, so eligible for the garbage collector. But they'd be eligible and collected anyway the next time *R* needed memory, so there is no value in explicitly calling the garbage collector.

It's maybe interesting in the example below that the value of `finally` is not captured, so `finally` is being used purely for its side-effects. One might want to use `finally` (it's not required!) if the expression were, say, opening a file or data base connection, and one wanted to be sure to close it whether an error occurs or not (see also `on.exit()`).

Here's some kind of an example to illustrate different components of `tryCatch()`.

```
fun <- function(n) {
    tries <- successes <- 0
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        result <- tryCatch({
            if (rnorm(1) < 0)
                stop("oops")
            successes <- successes + 1
        }, error=function(e) {
            NULL                        # suppress errors
        }, finally={
            tries <- tries + 1
        })
        message(if (is.null(result)) "NULL" else result)
    }
    c(tries=tries, successes=successes)
}
```

`fun()` takes an argument `n` representing the number of times to perform the body of the `for` loop. Each time through the loop, R generates a random normal deviate.

If the deviate is less than 0 (about 1/2 the time) an error is generated and the error handler `err=function(e) {...}` suppresses the error -- the user does not see the error message, and the iteration continues.

If the deviate is greater than or equal to zero, then the variable `successes` is incremented by one.

Regardless of whether an error is generated or not, the `finally={}` expression is evaluated and increments the value of `tries`.

The return of the `tryCatch()` statement is captured by `result`. If an error occurs, then `result` is the value of the error handler (NULL). If an error does not occur, then `result` is the value of the last line of the expression being evaluated by the `tryCatch()` -- `successes + 1`. 
The function prints out it's progress, and returns a named vector of tries and successes:

```
> fun_result <- fun(5)
1
NULL
2
NULL
3
> fun_result
    tries successes 
        5         3
```

Comment: That seems like a perfect answer, files and database connections of course... I should have known better. Not sure why you got a -1